# Why is Wordpress blocking the js livechat window?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, chatbot, bitrix

I have an issue launching a bitrix chat window on my Wordpress installation and it seems to be a JS issue. I am not able to identify exactly what is blocking this script and would like to have some help here.
The chat window is on this website.  https://www.escuelaconsciente.org/

This is the console message:

### `VM605:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'closeLiveChat' of undefined at <anonymous>:1:20 at Object.appendToHead (script.js:1) at Object.loadJs (script.js:1) at Object.evalGlobal (script.js:1) at Object.hide (script.js:1) at Object.unfreeze (script.js:1) at Object.<anonymous> (script.js:1)`

I have installed the js for the chat widget but Wordpress will block the chat window.

```
<script>
    (function(w,d,u){
            var s=d.createElement('script');s.async=true;s.src=u+'?'+(Date.now()/60000|0);
            var h=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];h.parentNode.insertBefore(s,h);
    })(window,document,'https://cdn.bitrix24.eu/b9992163/crm/site_button/loader_1_cvsict.js');
```

I expect the livechat window to open and be able to initiate a conversation with an agent.

Comment: Try to move your script inside footer before body closing tag. If you are using any cache plugin disable it to check weather it work or not.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. This is the current setup

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<!-- chatbot -->
<script>
        (function(w,d,u){
                var s=d.createElement('script');s.async=true;s.src=u+'?'+(Date.now()/60000|0);
                var h=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];h.parentNode.insertBefore(s,h);
        })(window,document,'https://cdn.bitrix24.eu/b9992163/crm/site_button/loader_1_cvsict.js');
</script>
<!-- chatbot -->
</body>
</html>

Comment: It looks fine to me, cross verify your code with their website widget code as mentioned at their website.  https://helpdesk.bitrix24.com/open/4112659/

Comment: If you have bitrix24 account then you can use their wordpress plugin as well. https://wordpress.org/plugins/integration-with-bitrix24/

Comment: Yes I am using it and it is working now. Thanks!